# How to add path of a program to $PATH environment variable?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a directory to my path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

I need to use a program in my job. I followed the installation instructions of this PROGRAM. However, when I try to run it the message appears - `program_that_I_want_to_run:Command not found`

I know that it is a `$PATH` problem, but I tried the command line described in the instructions and it did not work.

> 3. Set environment variable CONFIG_PATH
>
>    `export CONFIG_PATH=/my_path_to_PROGRAM/PROGRAM/config/`

I am sure that I indicated correctly the path to access the `config` directory. No typing errors.

Help?

Comment: Is it really necessary to obscificate your question ? It would be much easier to help you if you specified your program, how you installed it, and what the full path was. I am not sure if you need `export CONFIG_PATH=/my_path_to_PROGRAM/PROGRAM/config/` as your error message is one of PATH and not necessarily configuration, hard to know from what little you posted.

Answer (score 74):

Firstly, check your original path:

```
echo $PATH
```

It should show something like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Now add your program to that path, ensuring your using the entire path all the way from / to your program.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/my/program
```

This sets your PATH variable to the existing PATH plus what you add to the end. Check that it has been added (***Caveat***: it presist only in the current session of the terminal):

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: Is this permanent?

Comment: no this is not permanent, as i closed the terminal, reopen it and type 'echo $PATH'.. it didn't show me my new path in it.

Comment: If you want to make the change permanent, add this exact command to the end of `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @AlexLomia: You are the king!

Answer (score 23):

Add this line to ~/.bashrc (you use PATH rather then CONFIG_PATH)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to_directory_containing_program
export CONFIG_PATH=/my_path_to_PROGRAM/PROGRAM/config/
```

Comment: Environment variables should be set in either ~/.pam_environment or ~/.profile, not ~/.bashrc.

Comment: [documentation for persistent environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables)

Comment: @galath- You do understand that this question is both a duplicate and over 3 years old ?  The link you give is more recent then the original question.

Comment: I came to this page from google and appreciate galaths comment a lot. Thanks

Comment: How to use that all without leaving terminal?