# How to add a folder in environment variable permanently

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, .profile

I know similar questions have been asked before on here (for example: [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path))

However, I don't know what to add and where to add this.

If I open `~/.profile`, it looks like this:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Now I want to add a directory to this

```
/home/newsof/mypackage/TT/V1_1
```

How can I add this permanently?

Comment: @Zanna please read above, I know this is said before, I just could not use the previous answer understandable. I mentioned that in my text

Comment: I read your question, but I don't see your challenge. The answers to that post are very good. Add a new line to the end of your `~/.profile` saying `PATH=$PATH:/home/newsof/mypackage/TT/V1_1`

Comment: @Zanna if I do that then I also should export PATH=$PATH:/home/newsof/mypackage/TT/V1_1   ? it is a temporary solution as it is said in another post like this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/109381/how-to-add-path-of-a-program-to-path-environment-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1 and this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/402353/how-to-add-home-username-bin-to-path?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: no you don't need to export it (that is temporary as you say), just log out and log back in or type `source ~/.profile` It's permanent

Comment: @Zanna  really sorry for asking too many questions. what will happen to the other path default ? is it not better to add this one ?   PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH:/home/newsof/mypackage/TT/V1_1"

Comment: @Zanna: Well, the reason why `export`ing isn't necessary in this case is that `PATH` already exists as an environment variable. It's not related to temporary vs. persistent.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I think I understand that, I meant that if OP did not change any config and ran export PATH=foobar then it would not persist (but in other situations we do want to set PATH temporarily and run such a command)

Comment: @Zanna: I know you know it. But it wasn't clear from your comment. ;)

Comment: @nik nothing will happen to it, since it gets set again, you are adding to it. if I do `FOO=bar ; FOO=$FOO:bar ; echo $FOO` I will get `bar:bar`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson :D thank you for clarifying. It must be bedtime here...

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson thanks for your valuable comments

Comment: You're very welcome! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/etc/environment` to set PATH environment variable, but it does not support variable expansion.

See this [Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) to get more information about enviroment variables

Comment: better to set it locally, unless there is a very good reason for using `/etc/environment`