# "Envoriment variable PATH" on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, apt, bash

When we install a program using **apt-get**, after installed it's available in terminal, normally, when we just call "your name" independent of context directory we are.

On Windows, when we add a path to envoriment variables in variable PATH all programs or files in this path are available in terminal (prompt command) to be called.

In Ubuntu, how does it when we want to make a program callable but it is a standalone file installed **without apt-get or aptitude**?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Like Windows you can add directory to the PATH variable. You can also create a `bin` directory in your home folder such as `/home/andre/bin` and put your programs in the `bin` folder. Ubuntu would know how to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux as well as on Windows we can add a ***path*** to the environment variable `$PATH` and all programs in this ***path*** will be available as shell commands. This topic is covered by the questions:

- [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)
- [How to add path of a program to $PATH environment variable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109381/how-to-add-path-of-a-program-to-path-environment-variable)
- [How to add /home/username/bin to $PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402353/how-to-add-home-username-bin-to-path)

On Linux is also available and different approach. Here are few available *standard* directories where we can put our executable files or symbolic links to them. This topic is covered by the questions:

- [Differences between /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/sbin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local)?
- [How to understand the Ubuntu file system layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout)
- [Where should I put my script so that I can run it by a direct command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465109/where-should-i-put-my-script-so-that-i-can-run-it-by-a-direct-command)